# NestJs - mongoose - Dynamic collection naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'd like to use dynamic collection names based on current year.

For example: From 'products' to 'products2020'.

Using NESTJS, I have to import "module.forFeature" with an specifyc collection name.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose'

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'Products',
        schema: ProductsSchema
      }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [ProductsService]
})
```

And the same happens with injection at service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose'

import { Model } from 'mongoose'

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Products')
    private readonly productsModel: Model<Products>
  ) {}
}
```

And finally, here's my schema:

```js
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'

export const ProductsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: { Type: String, required: true },
    code: String
  },
  {
    collection: 'Products'
  }
)
```

Is there some way to achieve dynamic naming?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why can't you just keep `year` property on documents in the `Products` collection?

Comment: @ethane Beacuse it's a requirement to handle it with that dynamic naming.

Answer (score 1):

I stumble into a similar issue, and the way I resolved was using the `MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync` method. The model and schema declaration are the same as in the [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection).

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: UsersModel.name,
        imports: [EnvironmentModule],
        inject: [EnvironmentService],
        useFactory: (envService: EnvironmentService) => {
          const env = envService.getEnv();
          const schema = UsersSchema.set(
            'collection',
            `${env.countryCode}-users`,
          );
          return schema;
        },
      },
    ]),
    ...
  ],
  providers: []
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looking for a solution to this kind of problem but i've hit a wall and there was no clear way to do it.

Below (minimal) code instantiate Services each bound to a specific model depending on a `country parameter`. i.e `ServiceX` bound to Model of Database X, `ServiceY` bound to the same Model in Database Y

But here is what i managed to do. You can absolutely do a work around to fit your needs

First comes the model/interface. Commonly used between different services

```
export interface User extends Document {
    readonly username: string;
    readonly password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.ObjectId,
        username: String,
        password: String
    },
    { collection: 'accounts', autoCreate: true }
);
```

Service definition is indeed the same for every model in different database/collection

```
@Injectable()
export class XUserService implements OnModuleInit{
    constructor(
        private userModel: Model<User>,
    ) {
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    async onModuleInit(): Promise<any> {
        console.log(`inside service dbname=: ${this.userModel.db.name} > ${this.userModel.collection.collectionName}` );
        // await new this.userModel({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), username: 'test', password: 'test', flag: this.c}).save()
    }

    async insert(){
        console.log(`inside service dbname=: ${this.userModel.db.name} > ${this.userModel.collection.collectionName}` );
        await new this.userModel({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            username: this.userModel.db.name,
            password: '0000'
        }).save();
    }

    async findOne(): Promise<User>{
        console.log(`inside service in : ${this.userModel.db.name} > ${this.userModel.collection.collectionName}` );
        return this.userModel.findOne()
    }
}
```

For Module, i made a `DynamicModule`

- Import DBConnections
- Create a Model for each need, ( for my case, one model in each Database )
- Create and bind each `Model` to a `Service`, so the instantiation of the service will be correct

```
@Module({

})
export class XUserModule{
    static register( /*use can pass parameter here*/): DynamicModule{
        return{
            module: XUserModule,
            imports: [
                DatabaseModule
            ],
            controllers: [
                XUserController
            ],
            providers: [
                // Create Models here, #1 and #2 in two different database
                {
                    provide: 'dz-'+'UserModel',
                    useFactory: (connection: Connection)=> {
                        return connection.model('User', UserSchema )
                    },
                    inject: [ dbname.shooffood('dz')+'Connection' ]
                },{
                    provide: 'ca-'+'UserModel',
                    useFactory: (connection: Connection)=> {
                        return connection.model('User', UserSchema )
                    },
                    inject: [ dbname.shooffood('ca')+'Connection' ]
                },

   
                // Create Providers/Services for each Model and Inject the Model to the Service by `TokenString`
                {
                    provide: 'dz' + XUserService.name,
                    useFactory: (m: any)=> {
                        console.log(m);
                        return new XUserService(m);
                    },
                    inject: [ 'dz-'+'UserModel' ]
                },{
                    provide: 'ca' + XUserService.name,
                    useFactory: (m: any)=> {
                        console.log(m);
                        return new XUserService(m);
                    },
                    inject: [ 'ca-'+'UserModel' ]
                }
            ],

            // Export your service with the same `provide` name for later usage.
            exports: [
                'dz' + XUserService.name,
                'ca' + XUserService.name
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Just FYI, database module looks like
Constants `dbname` are connection names and `uri` are the connection string.

```
const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: dbname.admin+'Connection',
        useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> => mongoose.createConnection(uri.admin),
    },{
        provide: dbname.system+'Connection',
        useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> => mongoose.createConnection(uri.system),
    },{
        provide: dbname.shooffood('dz')+'Connection',
        useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> => mongoose.createConnection(uri.dzfood),
    },{
        provide: dbname.shooffood('ca')+'Connection',
        useFactory: (): Promise<typeof mongoose> => mongoose.createConnection(uri.cafood),
    }
];

@Module({
    providers: [
        ...databaseProviders
    ],
    exports: [
        dbname.admin+'Connection',
        dbname.system+'Connection',
        dbname.shooffood('dz')+'Connection',
        dbname.shooffood('ca')+'Connection'
    ]
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

As for Controller, there is only one that handle each service via request param `:country`. But first i had to list all possible Models and services to include in the Application.

```
@Controller(':country')
export class XUserController {
    private byCountryServices = new Map();
    constructor(
        // Inject all required services by `tokenString`
        @Inject('dz' + XUserService.name) private dzUserService: XUserService,
        @Inject('ca' + XUserService.name) private caUserService: XUserService,
    ) {
        // Add to `<key, value>` Map for easy by param access
        this.byCountryServices.set('dz', this.dzUserService );
        this.byCountryServices.set('ca', this.caUserService );
    }

    @Get('post')
    async post(
        @Param('country') c: string
    ): Promise<string>{
        await this.byCountryServices.get(c).insert()
        return 'inserted in ' + c;
    }

    @Get('get')
    async get(
        @Param('country') c: string
    ): Promise<string>{
        console.log('param: ' + c)
        return await this.byCountryServices.get(c).findOne()
    }
}
```

Finally you import the module in AppModule with
`XUserModule.register()`

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for this, and after collecting some answers and websites, I finally figured out how to do dynamic naming of the collections.

Since I want all configured for also testing, I don't do a direct configuration of Mongoose in the AppModule import, but I use the nestjs config module. Still, I don't see why it shouldn't work for the direct configuration. In this example I am using two databases, one for the classic models (default), one for the dynamic (data). Let's start. You can find all the files [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-ubb4wd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Freports%2Freports.service.ts). In detail, what is important is the `reports.service.ts` that I will show below

```js
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection, InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { DeleteResult } from 'mongodb';
import { Connection, Model, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { Report } from './report.entity';
import ObjectId = Types.ObjectId;

@Injectable()
export class ReportsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Report', 'default') protected readonly model: Model<Report>,
    @InjectConnection('data') private dataConnection: Connection,
  ) {}

  getAll(): Promise<Report[]> {
    return this.model.aggregate().match({}).collation({ locale: 'en' }).exec();
  }

  find(id: string): Promise<Report> {
    return this.model
      .aggregate()
      .match({ _id: new ObjectId(id) })
      .collation({ locale: 'en' })
      .exec()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result?.length) return result[0];
        throw new HttpException('NOT FOUND', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      });
  }

  async update(id: string, objParams: Report): Promise<Report> {
    return this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, objParams);
  }

  async create(obj: Report): Promise<Report> {
    return this.model.create(obj);
  }

  async delete(obj: Report): Promise<DeleteResult> {
    return this.model.deleteOne({ _id: obj['_id'] });
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------
  // Here starts the dynamic collection part
  // ------------------------------------------------
  async saveData(reportId: string, data: any[], replace: boolean) {
    const collection = this.dataConnection.collection(reportId);
    if (replace) await collection.deleteMany({});
    return collection.insertMany(data);
  }

  loadData(reportId: string, filter: any = {}) {
    return this.dataConnection.collection(reportId).find(filter);
  }
}
```

Breaking down the elements, in the constructor we have
`@InjectConnection('data') private dataConnection: Connection`
that inject the connection. InjectConnection takes in input the name of the connection if you specified one in the AppModule, otherwise you can leave it blank.

Then `this.dataConnection.collection('customName')` makes the dynamic schema connection like what happens with the usual schema in the module with `MongooseModule.forFeature` and then with the injection of the model in the service constructor. Where I wrote `customName`, you can specify the name of the collection you want to use, a string, a variable, an environment variable, something you take from the database or from the controller request, or whatever source you want.

From that, we can use the usual Mongoose functions; in the latest two methods, we have an example of find, delete, and create many.

Feel free to ask questions if anything isn't clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

Using your connection you search for the client:

```
const client = this.productsModel.db.getClient();
const database = client.db("data base name");
const collection = database.collection("collection name");

const data = { test: "test" };
const insertOneResult = await collection.insertOne(data);
```